# How can I test "uploading a file" using Tornado unit tests?

Tags: python, unit-testing, asynchronous, file-upload, tornado

I'm want to test my web service (built on Tornado) using `tornado.testing.AsyncHTTPTestCase`. It says [here](http://www.peterbe.com/plog/tricks-asynchttpclient-tornado) that using POST for AsyncHttpClients should look like the following.

```
from tornado.testing import AsyncHTTPTestCase
from urllib import urlencode

class ApplicationTestCase(AsyncHTTPTestCase):
  def get_app(self):
    return app.Application()

  def test_file_uploading(self):
    url = '/'
    filepath = 'uploading_file.zip' # Binary file
    data = ??????? # Read from "filepath" and put the generated something into "data"
    self.http_client.fetch(self.get_url(url),
                           self.stop,
                           method="POST",
                           data=urlencode(data))
    response = self.wait()
    self.assertEqual(response.code, 302) # Do assertion

if __name__ == '__main__':
  unittest.main()
```

The problem is that I've no idea what to write at `???????`. Are there any utility functions built in Tornado, or is it better to use alternative libraries like [Requests](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests)?

**P.S.**
... actually, I've tried using Requests, but my test stopped working because probably I didn't do good for asynchronous tasking

```
  def test_file_uploading(self):
    url = '/'
    filepath = 'uploading_file.zip' # Binary file
    files = {'file':open(filepath,'rb')}
    r = requests.post(self.get_url(url),files=files) # Freezes here
    self.assertEqual(response.code, 302) # Do assertion
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to construct a `multipart/form-data` request body. This is officially defined in [the HTML spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#multipart-form-data). Tornado does not currently have any helper functions for generating a multipart body. However, you can use the `MultipartEncoder` class from the [requests_toolbelt](https://github.com/sigmavirus24/requests-toolbelt) package. Just use the `to_string()` method instead of passing the encoder object directly to `fetch()`.